# convolution 1d calculation how it actually work?

Tags: keras, time-series, conv-neural-network, convolution, tf.keras

I tried to implement 1d convolution with dilation

```
#keras.layers.Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, strides=1, padding='valid', data_format='channels_last', dilation_rate=1, activation=None, use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None)
# valid , causal , same 
conv = layers.Conv1D(1, 3, padding='same',
                     dilation_rate=1,
                     bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.zeros)
```

I want to understand how this dilation 1d convolution actually thraw the output

let say we have a input with

```
np.squeeze(sequence.numpy())
array([0.        , 0.32380696, 0.61272254, 0.83561502, 0.96846692])
```

and we have convolution filter with

```
np.squeeze(conv.trainable_variables[0].numpy())
array([-0.56509803,  0.89481053,  0.6975754 ])
```

and when we pass the convolution the output will be

```
output = conv(sequence)
np.squeeze(output.numpy())
array([0.        , 0.22587977, 0.71716606, 0.94819239, 1.07704752])
```

try to implement the wavenet 1dconvolution with dilation

I want to know how this output value calculated
 
and what if filter size and kernel_size change to different number?

> conv = layers.Conv1D(2, 3, padding='causal',
>                        dilation_rate=1,
>                        bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.zeros)
>
> conv = layers.Conv1D(3, 3, padding='causal',
>                        dilation_rate=1,
>                        bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.zeros)
>
> conv = layers.Conv1D(1, 3, padding='causal',
>                        dilation_rate=2,
>                        bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.zeros)
>
> conv = layers.Conv1D(2, 3, padding='same',
>                        dilation_rate=1,
>                        bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.zeros)
>
> conv = layers.Conv1D(3, 3, padding='same',
>                        dilation_rate=1,
>                        bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.zeros)
>
> conv = layers.Conv1D(1, 3, padding='same',
>                        dilation_rate=2,
>                        bias_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.zeros)

Comment: I can reproduce that output by prepending two 0's in front of your array, and then apply the kernel.

Comment: can you show me the full calculation process?

Comment: `[a[i]*k[0]+a[i+1]*k[1]+a[i+2]*k[2] for i in range(5)]` where `k` is your kernel and `a` is the array with two 0's prepended. With `same` padding, I would expect a `0` inserted before and after.

Comment: did you see the https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.03499.pdf wavenet's dilation(1) conv1d? how this Figure3 related with causal dilation 1dconv mentioned above?